# Задать относительный размер fixed элементу

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: TruenoRegular;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #fff;

}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;

}

nav {

    width: 100%;


}

.con {

    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

.menu {

    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;

    text-align: left;
    justify-content: space-around;

}

.menu ul {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

li {

    flex-grow: 1;
}


.menu .right a:hover {
    background-color: #ff7373;
}

.left,
.right {
    display: block
}

.right a {

    padding: 20px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.left a {
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.fix {
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid blue;

}

.nav_bar {

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;


    background: red;
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1
}
```

```html
 <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="con">

                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Delivery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Delivery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fix">
                        <div class="nav_bar"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Можно ли задать высоту .nav_bar -> `height: 100%;` не от высоты страницы(сейчас .nav_bar занимает всю видимую область ) а от самого блока .menu высота которого определяется по содержимому?
Ожидаемый результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> смотреть на полный экран

```js
$(function() {
  $('.trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav').show();
  });
  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav').hide();
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
  display: none;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
  transform: translateX(20px);
}

ul {
  transform: translateX(20px);
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.trigger {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.trigger span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #222;
  margin: 4px auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  margin: 30px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button class="trigger">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</button>
<div class="nav">
  <h2>Navigation of forum :</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item5</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item6</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Navigation of blog :</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item5</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item6</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="close" title="close window">x</div>
</div>




<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus quisquam neque tempora iusto perferendis.</h1>

  <div class="flex">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300/cc0" alt="">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Repellendus, ad neque quas sunt, similique minima nulla aliquid placeat eum aut veniam labore aliquam nemo eos provident. Placeat ea iste sed, rerum iusto omnis vel libero dolores non incidunt
      ipsam ipsum optio voluptates, quis reprehenderit amet. Aspernatur suscipit similique magnam aut dolore quaerat tempore repudiandae rerum labore, iusto earum pariatur distinctio modi et sequi ex necessitatibus architecto, consectetur veritatis ipsa
      voluptate voluptas tempora? Laudantium cupiditate aliquam dolor adipisci voluptatum, asperiores aliquid fugit vitae ea ipsum nisi ullam corrupti dicta. Nesciunt, fugit. Officiis reprehenderit, non rem quibusdam repellendus ex fugit sequi deserunt?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem commodi error est quae sit soluta qui aperiam et molestiae dolorum iusto corporis ad culpa eos accusantium voluptatem similique ipsum provident deserunt labore tenetur, velit deleniti? Voluptas
      perspiciatis cum exercitationem repudiandae eius nobis alias et ducimus quod ex quas minus esse animi eveniet nihil, ratione dolorem tempora quos eligendi. Quis odio ipsam blanditiis, tempore laborum ducimus natus. Officia suscipit recusandae architecto
      molestias, quae provident nihil molestiae aperiam! Rem consectetur placeat explicabo eum accusamus recusandae, quas quidem dignissimos dicta earum dolorum natus tempora quae laboriosam nulla beatae nisi maxime saepe, eaque alias.</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300/c0c" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/QBGrPP?editors=0010

Comment: Добавил ожидаемый результат в вопрос

Comment: что бы был одновременно fixed и имел такие размеры ?

Comment: Да именно так.Нет я конечно могу явно прописать эти 59px но этож костыль.

Comment: вот : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/QBGrPP

Comment: 59 пикселей - это точно не стоит делать - обычный padding будет достаточно - подобрать его и всё

Comment: Встречалась с проблемой не четного количества пикселей, иногда непредсказуемо масштабировалось, то добавлялись, то убавлялись лишние пиксели. А с четными было норм.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь `position: absolute` для дочернего элемента

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute; 
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: там fixed, а ему relative не авторитет

Comment: Я сначала тоже думал что такой способ и для fixed подойдет а оказывается нет